# For loop to count from 1 to 7

Tags: java, loops, count

I have a code that works but my for loop does not count from 1 - 7.  Basically I need this loop to run and count 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

here is my code:

```
public class Course {
public static int a;
public static String code;
public static int CreditHours;
Course() {} 
Course(int newA) {a = newA;}
public static int getCourse(int newA) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i = i + 1) {
        newA = i;
        a=newA;
    }
    return a;
```

here is what my output is:

```
course Objects each has a code (e.g. IT1006) and credit hours (e.g. 6)
The number inside the [] is the display order number
The number inside the () is the credit hours
[7] IT2249 (6)
```

I need the [7] IT2249 (6) but I need to start at [1] and count up to the [7]

This is for an academic assignment.

Comment: Please tag the language you're discussing

Comment: You go through your entire loop before returning the final result, which will always be 7. Maybe you want to throw a print statement in your `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

To give you a completely accurate answer I would have to see how you are initializing your class and calling the getCourse(int) function. But to at least point you in the right direction - the issue is that you are not looping whatever your printing function is. You need to move your for-loop outside and surround your getCourse(int) function.

Here is an example of what your code MIGHT look like:

```
public class Course {
    public static int a;
    public static String code;
    public static int CreditHours;
    Course() {} 
    Course(int newA) {a = newA;}
    public static int getCourse(int newA) {
        newA = i;
        a=newA;
        return a;
    }
}

//outside your Course class, wherever your print function is in, main?

for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i = i + 1) {
     int courseNumber = Course.getCourse(i)
     System.out.println("["+courseNumber+"]");
}
```

Cheers

Comment: `i = i + 1` can be simplified to `i++`

Answer (score -1):

Javier Gonzalez got me to the answer.  I removed the getCourse method completely and moved the for loop to the output statement.

Here is the method repair:

```
public class Course {
    public static int a;
    public static String code;
    public static int CreditHours;
    Course() {} 
    Course(int newA) {a = newA;}
```

and here is the output statements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Quenten's Copy");
    System.out.println("course Objects each has a code (e.g. IT1006) and 
    credit hours (e.g. 6)");
    System.out.println("The number inside the [] is the display order number");
    System.out.println("The number inside the () is the credit hours");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        a = i;
    System.out.println("[" + a + "] " + Course.getCode(code) + " (" + Course.getCreditHours(CreditHours) + ")");
    }
}

}
```

Here is the final output:

```
course Objects each has a code (e.g. IT1006) and credit hours (e.g. 6)
The number inside the [] is the display order number
The number inside the () is the credit hours
[1] IT1006 (6)
[2] IT4782 (3)
[3] IT4789 (3)
[4] IT4079 (6)
[5] IT2230 (3)
[6] IT3345 (3)
[7] IT2249 (6)
```

Thanks for the help.  I wasn't sure how to get the for loop to run properly but now I realize that it has to be running while the output is happening.